# how to send image data and other param from registration form to php

Tags: php, ajax

this is my ajax code

```
var fd = new FormData();    
            fd.append( 'file', $('#img')[0].files[0]);

var data = '&com='+company+'&loc='+location+'&year='+year+'&desc='+des+'&userid='+userid+'&fd='+fd;



        $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url: "insert.php",
             data : data,


                 success: function (response){



                 }
          });
```

this is php code

```
$conn =new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","test2");


 $company=isset($_POST['com']) ? $_POST['com']: '';

$local=isset($_POST['loc']) ? $_POST['loc']: '';
$year=isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year']: '';
$description=isset($_POST['desc']) ? $_POST['desc']: '';
$userid=isset($_POST['userid']) ? $_POST['userid']: '';


$query = mysqli_query($conn,"call exp('$userid', '$company', '$local', '$year', '$description')");

$target = "C:/xampp/htdocs/img/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

$Filename=basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    $conn =new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","test2");

   $query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO experience (image , PersonID) VALUES ('$Filename','$userid')");
    print_r($query);


} else {

    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

how to send param and image in ajax ....As i can send only image separately and data separately in data . as i have try many different code but not working perfectly

Comment: you need to set the content type appropriately in the ajax options.

Comment: how to set that

Comment: It's been asked many times before if you google it. Here's just one example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/5947043

Comment: i need pass multiple param data in to php..and i have tried many site code not working

Comment: well the code you've got now will never work. So I suggest you follow some examples which are shown to work. If you still can't get it right then post your updated code here. BTW building your querystring data by hand like that is a bad idea, you can get encoding issues. Just pass `data` as a JS object instead and let jQuery handle the encoding for you.

Comment: P.S. your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because you directly insert unsanitised user input into your query. use parameterised queries and prepared statements to better protect your data from hackers. See http://bobby-tables.com for an explanation of the problem and also some examples of how to do it safely using PHP/mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var guestbookSendMessage = new FormData();

guestbookSendMessage.append('com',company);
guestbookSendMessage.append('loc', location);
guestbookSendMessage.append('year',year);
guestbookSendMessage.append('desc',des);
guestbookSendMessage.append('userid',userid);

guestbookSendMessage.append('file', $("#img")[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url: "insert.php",

             data : guestbookSendMessage,
             cache: false,
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,


                 success: function (response){



                 }
          });
```

this how its done.....